# Component above react navigation's TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to create a simple layout.
I have a header component and beneath it I have a navigation tabs with content (see sketch - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyM6q.jpg).
I wish to achieve this with react navigation or react native navigation.
The reason I don't want to use react-native-tab-view is because it's not maintained and have a lot of bugs.

EDIT: I just found out that React navigation uses react-native-tab-view  for displaying tabs. Therefore if you are looking for a solution, either use @user:568754 answer bellow or use react-native-tab-view with a header

Comment: do you want to scrollable tab view ?

Comment: @HardikVirani yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the MaterialTopTabNavigator component in react-navigation.

Here is some sample code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class Head extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 200, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}/>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

const RootNav = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

class RootScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Head />
        <RootNav />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default RootScreen;
```

And a link to an Expo snack to preview: https://snack.expo.io/@bra/creatematerialtoptabnavigator-example

Comment: There is no Head component in your solution. Just the tabs and a title. I need a component above the tabs. See the sketch https://imgur.com/a/9H7FMYU

Comment: I have updated my code to use a component rather than a standard navigation header.

Comment: Please accept my answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes. exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to do something like this with react-navigation 5? I keep getting an error because in the updated version creating a navigator doesn't take in any arguments.